Countable many copies of $[0,1]$
Is $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ is separable? I’m trying to construct a countable basis from a countable basis of $[0,1]$ to show is separable but i’m not sure if i understand correctly the space.
My teacher says that i’ve to use the fact that the set of finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ is countable. If someone can give me a hint i’d appreciate it.

The union of countably many countably sets in countable.

Really you want the equally valid fact that the set of finite tuples from a countable set is countable. Do you see how the set of finite tuples of elements of a (countable) base for $[0,1]$ correspond to a base for $[0,1]^{\mathbb N}$?

What do you mean by "separable"? It sounds like you're using it to mean "there is a countable base for the topology" but nowadays it usually means "there is a countable dense set of points". Both are true for $[0,1]^\mathbb N$ but it would be nice to know exactly what you are trying to prove. The space $[0,1]^\mathbb R$ has a countable dense set but does not have a countable base.

@user14111 i’m trying to use separation axioms because the question is from that chapter. So if a space is second countable (has countable basis), then is separable and lindelof

srry, countability axioms*

@benjv Yeah, proving second countability is a valid way to prove separability and works here (and no real reason not to prove the stronger statement if you can), but of course it won’t always work since there are separable spaces that aren’t second countable.

Consider an open subset $U\subseteq [0,1]^\mathbb{N}$. Then $U$ is of the form $\bigcup U_i$ where each $U_i$ is of the form $\prod V_j$, where finally each $V_j$ is open in $[0,1]$ and all but finitely many $V_j$ (per $U_i$) are actually equal to $[0,1]$.
What this means is that given $U$ we can always find $(q_n)$ such that: (1) $(q_n)\in U$, (2) $q_n\in\mathbb{Q}$ for all $n$ and (3) $q_n=0$ for all but finitely many $n$. The choice of $0$ is arbitrary btw, it can be any fixed number.
Properties 2+3 imply that the set of all such sequences is countable. Indeed it can be expressed as countable union of finite products of countable sets. And property 1 implies that it is dense.
